# Finding inverses of two functions and their compositions to solve for unknown.

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

$$f(x) = 23x + 27,\;\; g(x) = 12x - d$$

I've found $f^{-1}(x),$ and $\,g^{-1}(x)$, but I don't know how to solve for $d$, given

$$f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x)) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(x)).$$

How do I do this please?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  You'll likely get better answers if you (a) format your equations for readability by looking [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and (b) explain what you've tried already so that we can meet you where you are in the problem rather than starting from the beginning.

Comment: I have managed to find f^-1(x) and g^-1(x), but from here on I am unable to do this equation. I have tried equalling the two equations and rearranging for d but that always gives d to be 0. Which is not the answer according to my lecturer.

Comment: You don't set the inverses equal to one another, you set the compositions of the inverses equal to one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find $f^{-1}(x)$, $g^{-1}(x)$.

$f^{-1}(x):\quad$ Express $x$ as a function of $y$: $y = 23x+ 27\iff \dfrac{y-27}{23} = x$. Switch $x$ and $y$: $$y = \frac{x-27}{23} \implies f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x-27}{23}$$

Similarly found, $g^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{x+d}{12}$.

Now compose $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))$ and $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x))$ and set the two compositions equal to one another (since we are given that the compositions are equivalent.)

Solve for $d$.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say i found the inverse of both functions. But I am not sure what to do from here.